# How to correctly render a texture orthogonally in OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I'm trying to render a 2D texture in an orthogonal projection.
Let me know what's wrong.
width and height are 128, the view is 256px wide and tall, so I expect the texture to be scaled 2x.
But all I get is this:

[image]

Code:

```
@interface ModNesOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView {
   @public
      char *pixels;
      int width;
      int height;
      int zoom;
}
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds;
- (void) free;
@end

@implementation ModNesOpenGLView

-(void) awakeFromNib {
   self->pixels = malloc( self->width * self->height * 3 );
   memset( (void *)self->pixels, 0, self->width * self->height * 3 );

   for( int y=0; y<self->height; ++y )
   {
      for( int x=0; x<self->width; ++x )
      {
         char r=0,g=0,b=0;
         switch( y%3 ) {
            case 0: r=0xFF; break;
            case 1: g=0xFF; break;
            case 2: b=0xFF; break;
         }
         [self setPixel_x:x y:y r:r g:g b:b];
      }
   }
}

-(void) setPixel_x:(int)x y:(int)y r:(char)r g:(char)g b:(char)b
{
   self->pixels[ ( y * self->width + x ) * 3 ] = r;
   self->pixels[ ( y * self->width + x ) * 3 + 1 ] = g;
   self->pixels[ ( y * self->width + x ) * 3 + 2 ] = b;
}

-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds
{
   glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

   glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, self->width, self->height, 0,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) self->pixels );
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); // GL_LINEAR
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP); 
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//   glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 ,0, 0, self->width, self->height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*) self->pixels );

   glBegin( GL_QUADS );
      glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,   0.0);
      glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(self->width, 0.0);
      glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(self->width, self->height);
      glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,   self->height);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();
}

- (void)prepareOpenGL
{
   // Synchronize buffer swaps with vertical refresh rate
   GLint swapInt = 1;
   [[self openGLContext] setValues:&swapInt forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];
}
```

(^ code scrolls down)

I realize I'm missing all the part about the initialization of the projection matrix and orthogonal projection.
I added it:

```
- (void)prepareOpenGL
{
   // Synchronize buffer swaps with vertical refresh rate
   GLint swapInt = 1;
   [[self openGLContext] setValues:&swapInt forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];

   glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glViewport(0, 0, self->width, self->height);
}
```

And then I get this:
[image]

I'm confused.

Here's where I got the code from: [code example](http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-draw-pixels-to-a-texture-opengl/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with coordinate systems and their ranges. Looking at the coordinates you use for drawing:

```
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(0.0,   0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(self->width, 0.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(self->width, self->height);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(0.0,   self->height);
```

The OpenGL coordinate system has a range of [-1.0, 1.0] in both x- and y-direction if you don't apply a transformation. This means that (0.0, 0.0), which is the bottom-left corner of the quad you are drawing, is in the center of the screen. It then extends to the right and top. The size of the quad is actually much bigger than the window, but it obviously gets clipped.

This explains the original version and resulting picture you posted. You end up with the top-right quadrant being filled, with a very small fraction of your texture (about one texel).

Then in the updated code, you add this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, self->width, self->height);
```

The viewport determines the part of the window you draw to. Since you say that `width` and `height` are 128, and the window size is 256x256, this call specifies that you only want to draw into the bottom-left quadrant of your window.

Since everything else is unchanged, you then still draw the top-right quadrant of your drawing area. So you end up filling the top-right quadrant of the bottom-left quadrant of the window, which is exactly what you have in the second image.

To fix this, the simplest approach is to **not** set the viewport to a non-default value (remove the `glViewport()` call), and use coordinates in the range [-1.0, 1.0] in both directions:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f( 1.0f, -1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f( 1.0f,  1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f,  1.0f);
```

Another option is that you set up a transformation that changes the coordinate range to the values you are using. In legacy OpenGL, which you are using, something like this should work:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, self->width, 0.0, self->height, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Cool. How can I tell it's legacy OpenGL and what would be modern OpenGL?

Comment: Typical signs of legacy OpenGL are immediate mode rendering (using `glBegin()`/`glEnd()`) instead of storing vertex data in buffers, and not using shaders. I would call the Core Profile of OpenGL 3.2 and later "modern", as well as OpenGL ES 2.0 and later. There should be plenty of tutorials around if you for example search for "OpenGL core profile". If some self promotion is allowed, I also have a little article on the topic on my (sparse) personal web site: http://retokoradi.com/2014/03/30/opengl-transition-to-core-profile/.

Comment: Allowed and encouraged. Thanks!